# iphone:MFMessageComposeViewController non editable body

Tags: iphone

I am using `MFMessageComposeViewController` api to send the sms i am sending message body to this api by-----(any 3rd parti api is there for sending sms)
Can we add its on view above that api View.

```
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
                    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
                { NSLog(@"contact page MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText");
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

controller.body =[sharedInstance getsmsText];
```

giving some message to controller body and api during sending mail coming ,but user can edit it can change it.i dont want it to be changed by user.
any clue is appreciable
i am able to make image over the api view but problem is keypad coming over that view ..

Answer (score 4):

I dont think its possible using public APIs but certainly Apple doesn't go well with this. The [Apple reference for `MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) clearly mentions

> Important: The message composition interface itself is not
>   customizable and must not be modified by your application. In
>   addition, after presenting the interface, your application is unable
>   to make further changes to the SMS content. The user can edit the
>   content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored.
>   Thus, you must set the values of content fields, if desired, before
>   presenting the interface

So your app may be rejected if you do this.

Comment: ,thanks dear but but i dont want modification of  this user interface any alternative way

Comment: See this line "In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is unable to make further changes to the SMS content. The user can edit the content using the interface". So I dont think you can disable editing.

Comment: ,thanks dear i got that we can not disable editinging in any cost

Comment: hi please can u suggest me some third parti api to send the pre-specified sms by it and user must not be able to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a image of text you don't want to get change other wise there is no option to stop the edit the body of the iphone mail composer .

Comment: thnks a lot i will try it and let u know.

Comment: can u tell me the way to convert a string into image is it possible to store the image on that string type variable .

Comment: you cann't covert a text to image but what  you can do if any text you are displaying on view then you can grab a sanpshot of particular region and then attach that image to your email body

Comment: I’m Busy SMS Lets You Send Predefined Message to Caller Easily               http://www.blogtechnika.com/im-busy-sms-lets-you-send-predefined-message-to-caller-easily